# How can I remove the # delimiter symbol when displaying a mysql field in my website

Tags: php, mysql

I'm pretty new to PHP and would value some help.
I have a mysql field which shows a range of garment sizes seperated by the # tag,
i.e. S#M#L#XL

I would like to display this on my website just as S M L XL without the # symbol.
Is there a way using PHP to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
str_replace("#", " ", $yourstring);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're looking to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string based on the hash. If so: `$sizesArray = explode('#', $sizes);`

If instead you're simply looking to replace the hash, you could use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
str_replace('#', ' ', $sizesString); // Will simply replace # with a space
```